# C++ source code line that stops execution and starts Visual Studio debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Is there a line of source code in C++ that will pause execution and start the debugger? Basically, I'm looking for the Matlab `keyboard` [functionality](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/keyboard.html).

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and compiling in Debug mode.

I know I can set a breakpoint in the source code editor, insert a desired list of command arguments in the project properties, and use the Debug > Start Debugging (F5) option. But I'd like to be able to run the program from the command line and still get to the Visual Studio debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [__debugbreak()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f408b4et.aspx). It sets a breakpoint in your code (something, that was achieved on x86 using `__asm int 3;` instruction).

When such breakpoint is encountered in application executed without debugger, you will be prompted to run it. You will see window similar to this one:

[image]

Then, you can run new instance of Visual Studio or attach already running one.

**EDIT**

Oh, one more thing: you can also attach debugger to any running process in your system.

In Visual Studio, click: `Debug` -> `Attach to Process` and then select desired process.